# Chrome on MacOS, audio onended fires as soon as audio starts

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio

I am playing audio file using HTML Audio Element / P5JS Sound add-on. After audio is ended, I need to perform actions.
I have registered callback for onended / ended event. This event is fired correctly on chrome on Windows but not on chrome on MacOS. **On MacOS, onended is fired as soon as audio starts.**

Here is sample code for HTML5 Audio elemtn I am using:

```
var myAudio = new Audio("https://example.com/myaudio1.mp3");

// Use onended event
myAudio.onended = function() {
    // Do something here
}

myAudio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    // Do something here
});

myAudio.play();
```

I have done similar code using [P5 JS](https://p5js.org/) with [Sound add-on](https://p5js.org/reference/#/libraries/p5.sound).

Does anyone has faced similar issue on Windows or any other OS? And if you have found solution, please let me know. That will be great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer?